# Javascript to read a select value in one field and provide a different value in another

Tags: javascript

In very basic language (because my understanding IS very basic), I have a select element in a form with the ID "alphascore" and, based on 3 possible values, translate what is selected in alphascore to a new value in a form element named "percentscore."

**Example:**

```
<td class="bold">Math Test</td>
<td><input type="text" ID="numscore" name="num" size="4" value=""></td>
<td>
    <select id="alphascore" name="">
        <option value="">Select Level Achieved</option>
        <option value="H">Honors</option>
        <option value="M">Met Requirements</option>
        <option value="N">Not Passed</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td><input type="text" id="percentscore" name="percent" size="4" value=""></td>
```

If the student achieves an H in the "alphascore", I want the value in the "percentscore" field to be 85, if the student achieves an M in the "alphascore", I want the value in the "percentscore" field to be 75, and if the student achieves an N in the "alphascore" I want the value in the "percentscore" to be 10.

I keep reading about "onchange" and I do understand the elementid.  I can even get JavaScript to copy the value from one field to another.  But I don't seem to be able to wrap my tiny little brain around how to evaluate the entry in one field to create a corresponding value in another field.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want to update the option value from `H` to 85, when user select `H`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/kqEa6/2/) here

```
    $("#alphascore").change(function () {

    var result = $("#alphascore").val();
    var score = 0;

        if (result == "H"){
            score = 85;
        }else if (result == "M"){
            score = 65;
        }else if (result == "N"){
            score = 10;
        }

    document.getElementById('percentscore').value = score;
});
```

the use of `id` in simple to explain, is mean the location or reference of your `<tag>`

In the above demo, you should include a `jquery.js`

**In JavaScript:**

If you want a pure JS solution, check [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/kqEa6/4/) here.

Add an `onchange` event on your `<select>` tag and call a `function`

```
<select id="alphascore" name="" onchange="myOption(value)">
```

This would be your javacript function:

```
function myOption(result){
        if (result == "H"){
            score = 85;
        }else if (result == "M"){
            score = 65;
        }else if (result == "N"){
            score = 10;
        }

    document.getElementById('percentscore').value = score;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a "jQuery" tag or it mentioned in the question. Given that you are asking the OP to include a large library and learn an a new syntax just to add a listener, that's a bit over the top. Also, don't post answers elsewhere, the code should be here.

Comment: Yupz. After I solved the question then only I realized there is only `"JS"` tag. Therefore I update a `JS` solution too. Now the OP can have two hands reference.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I do have access to jquery and I'm sorry I neglected to mention that detail.  Still learning, for sure - but THANK YOU to everybody who answered!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onchange listener to the select element so that values are updated when its value changes. Note that different browsers have slight differences in when select elements dispatch change events, however it shouldn't matter here.

```
<select id="alphascore" name="" onchange="updateScore(event);">
    <option value="" selected>Select Level Achieved</option>
    <option value="H">Honors</option>
    <option value="M">Met Requirements</option>
    <option value="N">Not Passed</option>
</select>
```

And the function can be:

```
function updateScore(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var form = element.form;
  var scores = {h:85, m:75, n:10};
  form.percent.value = scores[element.value.toLowerCase()] || '';
}
```

*toLowerCase* is used on the value to ensure it matches the *scores* object properties (you could also change the property names to upper case and use *toUpperCase*).

If you want to add the listener dynamically, add the listener using:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('alphascore').onchange = updateScore;
}
```

however, for simple tasks, inline listeners are fine.

Comment: You really helped me understand a great deal with your example.  I just happened to try the other one first, and it worked.  I've tucked your code away for future reference.  Thank you so much for responding!